# Is the wildcard character allowed on PHP prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, wildcard

I'm using AJAX to send the user's input to a PHP script. The PHP script shows records from a MySQL table.

If the user enter the wildcard character (`%`) then all the records from the database are listed.

Is this OK from a coding perspective? Should be the `%` char allowed? Or could my code be wrong?

I really don't care from the user experience, actually this could be a good feature, but I want to know if this is a *normal behavior for prepared statements*.

---

```php
...
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblStudent where lastNameStudent LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

When I set `$lastname='%'` I get all the records in the `tblStudent` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this fine from the code perspective?

Yes.

> Should be the % char allowed?

Nothing wrong with it. At least from security point of view.

Speaking of the application logic - it depends. You may escape this character if you want it be searched literally, or not escape if you want to use it as a wildcard.

This behavior has nothing to do with prepared statements.
A prepared statement is just a way to put a variable into query. The content of this variable is none of its business.

Comment: The content of the variable **is** of it business. That is why it uses [predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).

Comment: Agree with that. But remember that in PHP the type could be defined by its content.